# SslStream Set Cipher Suites

Tags: c#, ssl

I am trying to connect to a server via a SslStream from a C# .Net application.

When I try to authenticate with the server I receive an error on the client side saying *Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.*

On the server side the error appearing is: *Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common.*

In Java, the following code works to set the cipher:

```
SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socket;
String[] suites = sslSocket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
```

Would someone be able to tell me what the equivalent is in C#?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

this problem occur because you calling with different cipher-suit, to make successful communication you have to choose suit common at both end because different suit produce different cipher text

following are the suits provided by default[you can also make your one]

```
C#-
SslAlgorithms.ALL |
SslAlgorithms.RSA_3DES_168_SHA |
SslAlgorithms.RSA_AES_128_SHA |
SslAlgorithms.RSA_AES_256_SHA |
SslAlgorithms.RSA_DES_40_SHA |
SslAlgorithms.RSA_DES_56_SHA |
SslAlgorithms.RSA_RC2_40_MD5 |
SslAlgorithms.RSA_RC4_128_MD5 |
SslAlgorithms.RSA_RC4_128_SHA |
SslAlgorithms.RSA_RC4_40_MD5 |
SslAlgorithms.SECURE_CIPHERS | SslAlgorithms.NULL_COMPRESSION

Java-
"SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5",
"SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA",
"TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
"TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
"SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5",
"SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA",
"SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5",
"TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA",
"SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5",
"SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA"
```